# Jquery hover out and animated imperfection

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Try to hover in really fast in my demo http://www.bootply.com/SIZ6SAdcWY

You'll see the imperfection, because the user may hover in again when the animate event is running, how to overcome such issue?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ More information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write about .stop() method in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/stop/. This method will stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements. In your case if you set .stop(true, true) before animation and css methods, hover will work correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').not('.box .box-lower').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({ "margin-top": "+=108px" }, "normal");
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({opacity:1,'transition': 'opacity 0.3s ease 0.35s'});
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).css({'margin-top': '92px'});
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({opacity:0,'transition':'none'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If some long animation is started and then the mouse leaves, then the animation is still running AFTER the hover out.

Added some stop() calls to end it

http://www.bootply.com/2T8MaPakDU